# A way to show all the 3D curve, with view still centered on {0, 0, 0}

Tags: plotting, graphics, differential-equations, graphics3d, output

I frequently have this graphics output problem :

I draw a 3D curve using `NDSolve`, and depending on the initial data, there's no way I could predict the **shape** and **extent** of the curve in 3D space.  In the `ParametricPlot3D` code, I could use `PlotRange -> All` to show the whole curve, but then the 3D box isn't centered on the origin : `{0, 0, 0}`.  Rotating the view is annoying in this case.  I could use something like

`PlotRange -> {{-100, 100}, {-100, 100}, {-100, 100}},`

but most of the time the box is too small or too large to display the whole curve.  The *scale* isn't adequate and there's no way I could predict in advance which scale should be best to show *all* the curve (and no more useless space, since it could be a pain to zoom in).

Using `FindMax`, I could find the fartest distance to the curve, from the origin, and use that value in `PlotRange`, but this may have a strong impact on performances in a `Manipulate` box (depending on the curve/solution complexity).  I much prefer to use another way to show the whole curve.

So my question is this :

> Using `PlotRange` (or another option ?), how can we tell Mathematica to show the whole curve, while maintaining the central view position on the origin (`{0, 0, 0}`) ?

**EDIT :** An example of a curve not centered on the origin :

```
ParametricPlot3D[
    {Sin[3 t] - 2, Cos[5 t], 0.03 t},
    {t, 0, 2Pi},
    PlotRange -> All, (* Not good in this case *)
    Boxed -> True,
    ViewVector -> {0, 0, 0} (* Ugly option *)
]
```

I need to show all that curve, while fixing the view centered on the origin, and have a *symetrical box all around the origin*.

Comment: Have you tried `ViewVector`? This maintainces the view Position on the origin.

Comment: How ?  Can you give a simple example of its use ?  The documentation isn't very helpfull for these things ; it always give useless and fancy examples !

Comment: Could you give an example of you curve? Btw, the 2. option you might Need is ViewAngle. This changes the visible range, without need of adjusting PlotRange etc.

Comment: Yes, I know the ViewAngle option, but then the problem is still the same :  how to define a proper scale ?

Comment: Just a quick example : `ParametricPlot3D[
 {Sin[3 t] - 2, Cos[5 t], 0.03 t}, {t, 0, 10 Pi},
 PlotRange -> All,
 Boxed -> True,
 ViewVector -> {0, 0, 0}
 ]`.

Comment: Please provide some data for your 3d curve, otherwise I'm not quiet sure what you are talking abut... thx

Comment: I just added a small example under the question.

Comment: `ViewVector -> {0, 0, 0}` is indeed an ugly option, meaning your camera is sitting @ {0,0,0}. Use `ViewAngle -> 20 Degree, ViewVector -> {{5, -5, 5}, {0, 0, 0}}` instead. Once you have adjusted a `ViewVector` you can Play with `ViewAngle`

Comment: The only solution I have than is adjusting the `ViewVector`automatically, by finding the center of the Plot via MaxValue-MinValue... Sorry for my missleading comments before...

Answer (score 3):

first make the plot and use `AbsoluteOptions` to get the range:

```
p=ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[3 t] - 2, Cos[5 t], 0.03 t}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> All,(*Not good in this case*)Boxed -> True, 
  ViewVector -> {0, 0, 0} (*Ugly option*)];(*<-this semicolon will be red, is ok*)
rad = Max@Abs@Flatten[ (PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[p])]
```

now combine the plot with a sphere ( or a cube or whatever ) that is centered and encompasses the figure.

```
Show[{Graphics3D[{Opacity[.1], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, rad]}], p}]
```

You can set `Opacity[0]` here if you don't want to see the sphere at all..but I think it sort of helps anyway.

[image]

drawing axes is another option:

```
Show[{Graphics3D[{Arrowheads -> {-.02, .02}, 
    Arrow[{-#, #}] & /@ Permutations[{0, 0, rad}]}], p}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: This solution is hard to apply to a numerical curve found with `NDSolve`, that may change inside a `Manipulate`box.  And is has a cost on performance.

Comment: You can put all that in `Mainpulate`. I think it doesn't add much overhead to generating the plot in the first place.. give it a try. Or put up a real example.

Comment: just noticed I forgot to assign the plot to `p`.. fixed. Hope that didn't confuse.

Comment: It's working.  I'll study this.

Comment: Since I don't want the sphere, this appears to work : `rad = Max[Abs[Flatten[(PlotRange/.AbsoluteOptions[graphicsName])]]];
Show[graphicsName, PlotRange -> rad{{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]`.  But I don't understand the `AbsoluteOptions`.  Could you add some comments in your answer about what your code is doing ?

Comment: `PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[p]` extracts the actual range that `ParametricPlot3D` determined for the plot. As I said you can make the sphere invisible with `Opacity[0]`, or draw any other thing in there that forces the 3d rendering to see a symmetric volume.  (A little warning `Opacity` may cause you problems if you need to export the graphics)

Comment: You don't need the sphere (or any other object), if you use your `rad` value in `PlotRange`.  This works.

Answer (score -1):

If I got that right I suggest the following solution for your example:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[3 t], Cos[5 t], 0.03 t}, {t, 0, 1 Pi}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, Boxed -> True, ViewAngle -> 20 Degree, 
 ViewVector -> {{0, -5, 5}, {0, 0, 0}}]
```

Now, play with the `ViewAngle` to adjust the angle of view...
[image]

Comment: You changed the function, which is now centered, so you have eliminated the source of the problem ("throwing the baby with the bath water").  Add "-2" to the "x" component.  Your solution doesn't work.

Comment: Sry, my mistake. Didn't realized, that I throw something important away...